# How to load this kind of matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file-io, matrix

I have an `upper triangular` matrix like:

```
A=  load('A.txt');

1.0    3.32   -7.23
       1.00    0.60
               1.00
```

I want to load it in MATLAB, and as this is symmetric converting it doing

`a = A + triu(A, 1)'`
 so at the end I will have a matrix `a`

```
1.0    3.32   -7.23
3.32   1.00    0.60
-7.23  0.60    1.00
```

the problem I am having is at the moment of loading:

```
>> A = load('A.txt');
??? Error using ==> load
Number of columns on line 1 of ASCII file C:\A.txt
must be the same as previous lines.
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [importdata](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/importdata.html) instead, [load](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/load.html) is usually only used for *.mat* files. How is your file *A.txt* structured? If it is like this,

```
1.0    3.32   -7.23
1.00    0.60
1.00
```

then you will get

```
A = importdata('A.txt')

A =

    1.0000    3.3200   -7.2300
    1.0000    0.6000       NaN
    1.0000       NaN       NaN
```

So you will have to shift the two last rows, like this

```
A(2,:) = circshift(A(2,:),[0 1])
A(3,:) = circshift(A(3,:),[0 2])

A =

    1.0000    3.3200   -7.2300
    NaN       1.0000    0.6000
    NaN       NaN       1.0000
```

and then replace the NaNs with 0s and use your expression to create a symmetric matrix.

```
A(isnan(A)) = 0;

a = A + triu(A, 1)';

A =

    1.0000    3.3200   -7.2300
    3.3200    1.0000    0.6000
   -7.2300    0.6000    1.0000
```

Comment: @darkcminor: You are right, see my updated answer. Your generalization of the shift was correct, but my method for making the matrix symmetric was not. The new answer should work better

Comment: Is it more efficient to use `A(isnan(A)) = 0;

a = A + triu(A, 1)';
` rather than  `A(isnan(A)) = A(isnan(A)');` I have a question A(isnan(A)) = 0 will make the lower triangular 0, right?

Comment: Yes, A(isnan(A))=0 will set all the NaNs to 0. Not sure about the efficiency, will have to test it, but I don't have Matlab at the moment.