# Make a general import of upper triangular matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have been trying to make a general import of [Ghaul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230115/how-to-load-this-kind-of-matrix-in-matlab/5230518#5230518) to my earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230115/how-to-load-this-kind-of-matrix-in-matlab) about importing an upper triangular matrix.

**Initial Data:**

```
1.0    3.32   -7.23
1.00    0.60
1.00

A = importdata('A.txt')

A =

    1.0000    3.3200   -7.2300
    1.0000    0.6000       NaN
    1.0000       NaN       NaN
```

So you will have to shift the two last rows, like this:

```
A(2,:) = circshift(A(2,:),[0 1])
A(3,:) = circshift(A(3,:),[0 2])

A =

    1.0000    3.3200   -7.2300
    NaN       1.0000    0.6000
    NaN       NaN       1.0000
```

and then replace the NaNs with their symmetric counterparts:

```
A(isnan(A)) = A(isnan(A)')

A =

    1.0000    3.3200   -7.2300
    3.3200    1.0000    0.6000
   -7.2300    0.6000    1.0000
```

**I have this, so we get the complete matrix for any size:**

```
A = importdata('A.txt')
for i =  (1:size(A)-1)
    A(i+1,:) = circshift(A(i+1,:),[0 i]);
end 
A(isnan(A)) = A(isnan(A)');
```

Is this approach the best? There must be something better. I remember someone told me to try not to use `for` loops in MATLAB.

**UPDATE**
So this is the result. Is there any way to make it faster without the loop?

```
A = importdata('A.txt')
for i =  (1:size(A)-1)
    A(i+1,:) = circshift(A(i+1,:),[0 i])
end
A(isnan(A)) = 0;
A = A + triu(A, 1)';
```

Comment: See my updated answer, I think that should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another general solution that should work for any size upper triangular matrix. It uses the functions [ROT90](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/rot90.html), [SPDIAGS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/spdiags.html), and [TRIU](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/triu.html):

```
>> A = [1 3.32 -7.23; 1 0.6 nan; 1 nan nan];  %# Sample matrix
>> A = spdiags(rot90(A),1-size(A,2):0);       %# Shift the rows
>> A = A+triu(A,1).'                         %'# Mirror around the main diagonal

A =

    1.0000    3.3200   -7.2300
    3.3200    1.0000    0.6000
   -7.2300    0.6000    1.0000
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way without loop. If you have a more recent version of Matlab, you may want to check which solution is really faster, since loops aren't as bad as they used to be.

```
A = A'; %'# transpose so that linear indices get the right order
out = tril(ones(size(A))); %# create an array of indices
out(out>0) = A(~isnan(A)); %# overwrite the indices with the right number
out = out + triu(out',1); %'# fix the upper half of the array
```

Comment: I've got MATLAB 7.11.0 (R2010b), so your solution is faster, right?, in lower versions of MATLAB??

Comment: @darkcminor: In old versions of MATLAB (I think < 2007, but I might be mistaken), it was very costly to do loops (because MATLAB basicly kept interpreting everything inside the loop). In newer versions, this is no longer the case so the performance gain might be smaller or non-existent in newer versions (a loop still results in a lot of function calls, which is inefficient). So it still makes sense to vectorize the code in most cases.

Comment: @darkcminor: I think my solution might be faster even with newer versions of Matlab (see @Egon's comment for an excellent explanation), though it needs more memory since you cannot simply overwrite `A`.

Comment: @Ghaul: Always a pleasure :). Good call on `importdata`, btw.