# Matlab error with "load" - any idea what might cause it?

Tags: matlab, file-io

I'm trying to load a text file into Matlab and getting an error message that doesn't make sense to me. The file is a very large text file containing 8 columns of numbers. The error message says:

> Number of columns on line 1308295 of ASCII file [filename.txt] must be the same as previous lines.

But as far as I can see there's nothing special about line 1308295. In fact that line has been in the file for months and the code hasn't complained before. So I wondered if there might be something else unrelated that could cause Matlab to give that error?

Comment: Try to create a copy of the file, delete line 1308295 and try again. Do you still get the error? It would also help if you posted that line and a few lines near it (for example, post lines 1308290 - 1308300)

Comment: Also check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230115/how-to-load-this-kind-of-matrix-in-matlab.

Comment: What happens if you manually import the file into Matlab's workspace?

Comment: Could you copy lines 1308293 through 1308297 into your question? Maybe somebody sees something special about the line with the error. Also, did you check for trailing spaces? I don't know if they would cause problems, but they're one of the things that can be hard to see and track down.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of text file is it? If it's a data file, you could try the "importdata" function.